# OnClickListener when app is in background

Tags: android

I'm developing an app. I need to know if its possible to capture screen co ordinates of touches using onclicklistener even when the app is in background.

Even when the app is not active, i need the coordinates to be fetched. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. System (aka Screen) overlay -
   https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256 and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
2. Custom AccessibilityService - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

However, both options requires user consent.